# How do you solve this SQL query?

Tags: sql

In this puzzle we have to group data based on Patients admission date and discharge date. If any Patients discharge date + 1 = admission date then we have group both rows into one row and sum costs from both the rows. Please check out the sample input and expected output for details.

```
Sample Input
PatientID   AdmissionDate   DischargeDate   Cost
1009        27-07-2014      31-07-2014      1050
1009        01-08-2014      23-08-2014      1070
1009        31-08-2014      31-08-2014      1900
1009        01-09-2014      14-09-2014      1260
1009        01-12-2014      31-12-2014      2090
1024        07-06-2014      28-06-2014      1900
1024        29-06-2014      31-07-2014      2900
1024        01-08-2014      02-08-2014      1800

Expected Output
PatientId   AdminssionDate  DischargeDate   Cost
1009        27-07-2014      23-08-2014      2120
1009        31-08-2014      14-09-2014      3160
1009        01-12-2014      31-12-2014      2090
1024        07-06-2014      02-08-2014      6600
```

I am unable to come up with a solution for this.

Use this to generate the table:

```
CREATE TABLE PatientProblem
(
PatientID integer,
AdmissionDate date,
DischargeDate date,
Cost numeric(20,2)
);
 
--Insert Data
INSERT INTO PatientProblem(PatientID,AdmissionDate,DischargeDate
,Cost)
VALUES
(1009,'2014-07-27','2014-07-31',1050.00),
(1009,'2014-08-01','2014-08-23',1070.00),
(1009,'2014-08-31','2014-08-31',1900.00),
(1009,'2014-09-01','2014-09-14',1260.00),
(1009,'2014-12-01','2014-12-31',2090.00),
(1024,'2014-06-07','2014-06-28',1900.00),
(1024,'2014-06-29','2014-07-31',2900.00),
(1024,'2014-08-01','2014-08-02',1800.00)
```

Comment: What database type are you using? Sql Server, Postgresql, MySql...

Comment: ...as the information hovering the `sql` tag says to add.

Comment: @Max, I found this question online. I am trying to implement this on Postgresql. The DDL what I have pasted above was a part of the question.

Comment: According to your requirement, does the following output ok?

1009,2014-07-27, 2014-08-23, 2120
1009,2014-08-31, 2014-09-14, 3160
1024,2014-06-07,2014-07-31,4800
1024,2014-06-29,2014-08-02,4700

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a gaps and islands problem. We usually solve this with window functions. With `LAG` you can see the previous row's values. This helps us to mark the rows that start a new date range per patient. By building a running count of the number of marks then, we get group numbers for the patients' date ranges.

```
select
  patientid,
  min(admissiondate) as range_start,
  max(dischargedate) as range_end,
  sum(cost) as total_cost
from
(
  select
    patientid, admissiondate, dischargedate, cost,
    count(marker) over (partition by patientid order by admissiondate) as grp
  from
  (
    select
      patientid, admissiondate, dischargedate, cost,
      case when admissiondate > lag(dischargedate) over (partition by patientid order by admissiondate) + interval '1 day' then
        1
      end as marker
    from mytable
  ) marked
) grouped
group by patientid, grp
order by patientid, grp;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d2ee8fede9bb999ada79310047e5ae27